# Determining user scrolling vs click animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fixed navbar that hides when a user scroll down; and appears when they scroll up. This works fine.
It is a single page scroller site.

The problem occurs when a user clicks a nav item, and they are subsequently scrolled down the page, the fixed nav disappears. I would like this to stay put when the nav item is clicked, until the user scrolls down themselves with the mouse wheel or scrollbar.

My approach this far has been to set a variable to determine if it is programmatic scrolling or not. I use that variable to determine if the nav should hide or not as a conditional statement.

```
window.programScrolling = false;
```

The nav item click function is as below, which sets the var to true.

```
$('a[href^="#"]:not([href="#"])').on('click',function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var target = this.hash;
  var $target = $(target);

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
  }, 500, 'easeInOutCubic', function () {

      window.programScrolling = true;

  });

});
```

This code does indeed work. But only once as now the variable is always true.

I need a way to reset that variable back to false when the user does the scrolling.

I have tried setting on the scroll event

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
   window.programScrolling = false;
});
```

But this seems to take precedence over the click event and hence that variable is now always false.

Any suggestions? Or alternative approaches?

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by `$(window).scroll` is taking precedence you mean it is called second, you can use this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if (programScrolling)
      window.programScrolling = false;
   else{
      //User initiated scroll!
   }
});
```